# Knockout Validation validatedObservable group error

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have a group of items that I need to validate as a whole. I setup a `validatedObservable` on the group, but the error message doesn't display.

I have a simplified example here. I want each number to be between 0-100 and the sum to be exactly 100. How do I handle this kind of validation?

**Update:** I know in this example I could just make a `ko.computed` and validate that, but that's not what I need.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CGuW2/5/

```
0-100:<input data-bind="value: num1, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/><br>
0-100:<input data-bind="value: num2, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/><br>
<span class="validationMessage" data-bind='text: isValidSum.errors()'></span>

ko.validation.rules['mustEqual'] = {
    validator: function (val, otherVal) {
        return (parseInt(val.num1()) + parseInt(val.num2())) == otherVal;
    },
    message: 'total must equal {0}'
};
ko.validation.registerExtenders();

var viewModel = {
    num1: ko.observable("50").extend({ number: true, min: 0, max: 100 }),
    num2: ko.observable("50").extend({ number: true, min: 0, max: 100 })
};

viewModel.isValidSum = ko.validatedObservable({
                            num1: viewModel.num1,
                            num2: viewModel.num2
                        }).extend({ mustEqual: 100 });

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: In Chrome I can see the "Please enter a value less than or equal to 100." if I enter large numbers...

Comment: Those errors messages are for each number. I also need to validate the group. Each number must be between 0-100, and the sum must equal 100. I updated the example because it was flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to bind on `text: isValidSum.error` instead of `text: isValidSum.errors()`. Also, it looks like you have to bind `visible: !isValidSum.isValid()` when you do this.

So my solution looks like this:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CGuW2/6/

```
0-100:<input data-bind="value: num1, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/><br>
0-100:<input data-bind="value: num2, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/><br>
<span class="validationMessage" data-bind='visible: !isValidSum.isValid(), text: isValidSum.error'></span>
```

Comment: granted this seems to work, but i don't think this is how it's intended to be done.  https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/issues/41 & it's example shows that you should pass in the result of the validatedObservable call to applyBindings as your root VM...but i can't get to work see https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/issues/202.  You have any further epiphanies?

Comment: I have had an epiphany. Things have changed since I posted my answer here (library versions) and the solutions I had no longer work. I posted a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408514/is-there-a-way-to-extend-validation-on-knockout-validations-validatedobservable) where I think I have a better answer for the libraries as they are today (ko 3.4, kv 2.0.3).

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle, I've implemented sum validation.

http://jsfiddle.net/CGuW2/3/

I think the problem was that you can not use `extend` on `validatedObservable`