# Is there a way to extend validation on Knockout Validation's validatedObservable?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I need to make sure each observable is valid and also make sure all the observables are valid together. In my simplified example I have a modelNumber and stockNumber that are each required, but together they must also form a valid partNumber. My attempt gives me this error:

"Uncaught Error: Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters."

What's the problem?

https://jsfiddle.net/yekr2ov2/18/

```
// enable validation
ko.validation.init();

ko.validation.rules['partNumberValid'] = {
  validator: function(partInfo, otherVal) {
    return partInfo.modelNumber() + partInfo.stockNumber() == "m1s1";
  },
  message: 'part number is invalid'
};
ko.validation.registerExtenders();

function VM() {
  var self = this;

  self.modelNumber = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
  self.stockNumber = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
  self.vinNumber   = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });

  self.isPartNumberValid = ko.validatedObservable({
    modelNumber: self.modelNumber,
    stockNumber: self.stockNumber,
    vinNumber: self.vinNumber
  }).extend({ partNumberValid: true });

  self.message = ko.observable();

  self.save = function() {
    if (self.isPartNumberValid.isValid()) {
      self.message("saved");
    } 
    else {
      debugger;
      //self.isPartNumberValid.errors.showAllMessages();
      self.message("not saved");
    }    
  };

}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

Comment: On a side note, isn't a [`ko.validation.group`](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Validating-Only-Specific-Observables) what you're actually after?

Comment: @Jeroen, almost. `ko.validation.group` would tell me if all of the parts are valid according to each of their validations. I'm also want to know if all of the parts together make a valid combination. So, after explaining it that way, I think I have an answer.

Answer (score 2):

i have modified the code and the following code works fine.

```
ko.validation.init();
ko.validation.rules['partNumberValid'] = {
 validator: function (partInfo, otherVal) {                           
              return partInfo.modelNumber() +''+ partInfo.stockNumber() === "m1s1";
            },
 message: 'part number is invalid'
           };
 ko.validation.registerExtenders();

 function VM() {
   var self = this;
   self.modelNumber = ko.observable().extend({required: true});
   self.stockNumber = ko.observable().extend({required: true});
   self.isPartNumberValid = ko.observable({                        
     modelNumber:self.modelNumber,
     stockNumber:self.stockNumber                                         
   }).extend({partNumberValid:true});

  self.validateMe = ko.computed(function(){
                        write:{
                            var tes = ko.validation.group([self.modelNumber,self.stockNumber,self.isPartNumberValid]);
                            tes.showAllMessages(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
  ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

Fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/yekr2ov2/7/
i used ko.validation.group to validate observables and computed to validate immediately. you can replace the computed with button click or any other custom function. Let me know if that helps.

thank you

Comment: This doesn't quite do it. It will make all of the validation messages appear, but it doesn't validate each part and the whole. I made an update to your example that shows `isPartNumberValid` will falsely look valid even when a part of its data is invalid.  https://jsfiddle.net/yekr2ov2/16/

Comment: Knockout validation plugin has an option to remove validation. so you can control the validation display, weather it is for some specific, or whole.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is you can't extend validation on Knockout Validation's validatedObservable. I think the right answer here is to create an `observable` for each thing or group of things that needs validation and then create a `validatedObservable` to validate all of those `observables`.

https://jsfiddle.net/yekr2ov2/17/

```
ko.validation.init();
ko.validation.rules['partNumberValid'] = {
  validator: function(partInfo, otherVal) {
    return partInfo.modelNumber() + partInfo.stockNumber() === "m1s1";
  },
  message: 'part number is invalid'
};
ko.validation.registerExtenders();

function VM() {
  var self = this;
  self.modelNumber = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
  self.stockNumber = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
  self.vinNumber = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });

  self.partNumber = ko.observable({
    modelNumber: self.modelNumber,
    stockNumber: self.stockNumber
  }).extend({ partNumberValid: true });

  self.isPartNumberValid = ko.validatedObservable({
    modelNumber: self.modelNumber,
    stockNumber: self.stockNumber,
    vinNumber: self.vinNumber,
    partNumber: self.partNumber
  });

  self.message = ko.observable();

  self.save = function() {
    if (self.isPartNumberValid.isValid()) {
      self.message("saved");
    } 
    else {
      debugger;
      self.isPartNumberValid.errors.showAllMessages();
      self.message("not saved");
    }    
  };

}
ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

Comment: BTW, when I put this to use in my code I noticed that `async` validation was not working. I had to change the partNumber from an `observable` to a `computed`. https://jsfiddle.net/yekr2ov2/19/

Comment: I faced the exact same problem as you. You saved my day !!